# Npm package for combinatorics

Tags: node.js, npm, combinatorics

I wonder is there any package in npm space used for combinatorics? Especially i'm interested with combinations without repetition. Is this function incuded in lodash?

Comment: Try this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-combinatorics

Comment: Thanks, I am suprised that there is no big package with this function included.